# CSS Menu with variable

Tags: jquery, css

I want to change the css menu that I have in my internet page, with a responsive menu, but I can not make it work. The menu is created by another file and applied as a variable, but does not run.In the current menu, I have a div with id menu, while in this div I have, I'm trying to identify the variable where to go to put the data files menu.php

```
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CSS3 animated & responsive dropdown menu</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/menu.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

</head>
    <body>
      <nav class="animenu"> 
      <button class="animenu__toggle">
        <span class="animenu__toggle__bar"></span>
        <span class="animenu__toggle__bar"></span>
        <span class="animenu__toggle__bar"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="animenu__nav" id="menu">>

      </ul>
    </nav>

        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <iframe name="principale" src="film.php" marginheight="50" height="800" width="100%" allowfullscreen = "true" ></iframe>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var menuRequest = $.ajax({
                    url: '/sito/menu.php'
                });

                menuRequest.done(function(data, status, xhr) {
                    var dynamicMenuWrapper = $('#menu');
                    dynamicMenuWrapper.html(data);
                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: Where is the css and on the top of your html page, in the <head> ... </head> do you have <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Comment: I did not realize that the post was not complete, I edited the post.

Comment: Hi, i cannot say anything unless i see the whole picture. But as far as i understand, there is a menu which is stored in a variable which is created by another php file. And you want to call that variable to show it on your page. Am i correct.

Comment: I'm not sure how old the prefixfree project is but you definitely don't have the viewport in your code

Comment: @Rüzgar Exactly, the file menu.php and what I am currently using with another menu and is working.

Comment: If php is involved the answer becomes more complicated. Because if you want to call a variable from another php file, first you have to require it. Like `require('menu.php');` But only if it is not already required from another constructor. Like a **controller.php** And not only that, your page should also be a **.php file** If all is well, then you can call the variable. But how you call it actually depends on how it is declared at the first place. Where to put that variable is the easiest part, if you manage to work it all out. But as i said earlier, i don't see the whole picture right now.